# Golang can't change template variable value

Tags: templates, variables, go

I have this code: http://play.golang.org/p/mPX1azLhlg but why I can't change my `$foo` value? How I supposed to do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://jan.newmarch.name/go/template/chapter-template.html

Answer (score 3):

This seems to have been updated in go1.11:
https://golang.org/doc/go1.11#text/template

> Modifying template variables via assignments is now permitted via the = token

So you need to change `{{$foo := 1}}` to `{{$foo = 1}}`

https://play.golang.org/p/hqWClmZfjcx

Answer (score 2):

> A variable's scope extends to the "end" action of the control
>   structure ("if", "with", or "range") in which it is declared, or to
>   the end of the template if there is no such control structure.

(http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)

Comment: how can I bypass this restriction?

Comment: You can define everything you need outside the template (in the go code), and then pass it inside.